# Parse.com and UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have simple xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <category><title>Привет!</title></category>
```

When I get it from cloud code (parse.com) like this:

```
     ...
     Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'http://path_to_xml/my_file.xml',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
           console.log(httpResponse.text);
        }
     ...
```

In log I see:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <category><title>ÐÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ!</title></category>
```

Xml file is in UTF-8 encode.
And it is not problem of log, because when I put httpResponse.text to string in object I see the same problem.

May be parse.com do not support UTF-8?

Thank You!

Comment: I fail to understand the benefit of parse.com. You put XML in, you get the XML out with broken characters. What's the benefit? And if the characters were not broken, what would be the benefit in that case? You would get exactly the same XML out.

Comment: I want to create a lot of object from xml, but when I get text from xml to my object column I see "ÐÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ!" but in xml - "Привет!". Xml is in utf-8, when I open it in Notepad++ or Sublime I see "Привет!" not "ÐÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ!".

Comment: @juhist benefit of parse.com is that I want to create job that parse xml every 15 min and create object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is that Cyrillic characters are using ISO-8859-5, so you are converting in utf8 and it's not reversible. Try to declare `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-5"?>`  and see the results.